# Ubuntu login loop mv .Xauthority not working

Tags: login

When I enter my username and password I am looped back to the login screen again.
I went to the shell screen and mv .Xauthority . Xauthority.bak is not working as it is saying /bin:/usr/bin is not included in the path environment variable.

Comment: Can you log into any other account? Do you know how to get to recovery mode and use root access tools?

Comment: @heynnema No I am not able to log into any other account.

Comment: You didn't answer the recovery mode question.

Comment: No I don't know.

Comment: Please see my answer. Please remember to accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: cd /home/utkarsh no such file or directory

Comment: Well, you have to give it the correct username directory. Do `cd /home` then `ls -al` to discover the correct name, then `cd to_the_correct_username`.

Comment: Sir it is showing drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov 2 21:27 .    drwxr-xr-x 26 root root 4096 Nov 1 19:35 . .    drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov 2 21:27  bak

Comment: My user name is in cd/home/bak/utkarsh

Comment: It's unusual to have your home directory in /home/bak/utharsh. Did you have a prior problem and move/backup your previous home directory? Do `cd /home/bak/utkarsh` and then do the `ls -al .*thority*` commands.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have a lot of information to go on, but lets try this...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type:

  - `sudo mount -o remount,rw /` # remount the disk as rw
  - `cd /home/bak/utkarsh` # change directory
  - `ls -al .*thority*` # list some files

You should see something like this...

```
-rw------- 1 utkarsh utkarsh 407910 Nov  2 08:56 .ICEauthority
-rw------- 1 utkarsh utkarsh     58 Jun 23  2017 .Xauthority
```

If it DOES NOT show `-rw-------` then...

- `sudo chmod 600 .*thority*` # change file protection

If it DOES SHOW `root root` then...

- `sudo chown utkarsh:utkarsh .*thority*` # change file ownership

**Note**: change `utkarsh` to your correct username

- `reboot` # reboot the computer

Reboot and see if you can log in.